# С# DataGridView проблемка с масивами

Tags: c#, winforms

хэлп, нужно с таблицы сохранить данные, потом переделать в string и сохранить в массив
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public string ArrToStr(object[] nums)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 14; ++c)
    {
        strnums[c] = array.nums[c]?.ToString();
    }
    return strnums;
}


public void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; ++j) {
            var testVar0 =  dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[j].Value;
            array.nums[j] = testVar0;
                    
            textBox1.Text = strnums[1];
        }
    }
}

class array
{
    public static object[] nums = new object[14];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы сразу в строки не писать

```
public static string[] nums = new string[14];
```

```
array.nums[j] = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[j].Value?.ToString() ?? "";
```

Вам одну строку надо? Вот так можно, например через пробел

```
string text = string.Join(" ", array.nums);
```

Comment: Там получается 14 ячеек (которые мы самостоятельно вводим после запуска) в таблице, нужно пройтись циклом по ним и при этом сохранить их в массив

Comment: https://ibb.co/nm5KhTw не понимаю почему

Comment: @W1rst потому что индексы в массиве с 0 начинаются, а не с 1

Comment: @W1rst а давайте так `public static readonly string[] nums = new string[14];` - в какой строке кода появится ошибка компиляции, в той вы и переприсваиваете массив. Эту часть кода вы не показали, а я тут телепата из себя строю.

Comment: @W1rst https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ подучите шарп чуть-чуть. Это не займет много времени.

Comment: В той части кода только создание таблицы, так https://ibb.co/wdwTgDv

Comment: @W1rst исключение в предыдущей строке возникло, это отладчик вам неправильно показал, обратите внимание на значение j внизу, там 14, а максимальный индекс 13. То есть в таблице у вас 15 колонок, а не 14. `public static readonly string[] nums = new string[15];` Ну или больше, я не знаю, сколько вы их создали.

Comment: Благодарю, капец я жестко тупанул